# How to pass PHP variable in Wordpress to JSON file?

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I like to send specific data from a post to my JSON response in Wordpress. I like to send the output of the variable "hatus" to the JSON response, but it does not seem to work.

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post($hatus); ?>
```

And here is the code I am trying to send it to:

```
<?php

// Export API Data to JSON, another method
add_action('publish_post', function ($ID, $post) {

    $wp_uri = get_site_url();
    $customApiEndpoint = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'; // or your custom endpoint

    $url = $wp_uri . $customApiEndpoint; // outputs https://your-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    $responseData = json_encode($hatus); // saved under the wp root installation, can be customized to any folder

    file_put_contents('your_api_data_backup.json', $responseData);

}, 10, 2);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here? The only thing I want is to show that 'hatus' variable outcome in my JSON response. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can send success JSON response by function `wp_send_json_success()` and error `by wp_send_json_error()`.
Check documentation [success](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) and [error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/).

But when you send a JSON response from PHP you should have a code that accepts it.
For example when you send data by AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ) ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'your txt or array ',
        success: function( data ) {   
            alert( data );
        }
    });
```

Inside function "success" you get your JSON array from PHP.

Comment: wp_send_json_success( array( 
    'name' => 'Andrew', 
    'call' => '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/', 
    'variable' => $hatus,
), 200 );

But this does not work. How?

Comment: @Johan when you send a JSON response from php you should have a code that accepts it( for example JS function). Do you have it?

Comment: Oh... no, I do not. I thought it was as simple as sending it to JSON :(

Comment: @Johan I've added example for this in my answer. It's just example with AJAX. But if you are using a different method, write the code example for JSON accept in your question

Comment: But should I amend my code above? Can I combine the two or should I change the above as well?

Comment: You can edit your question and add there